# Backreaction of FRW metric on QFT in curved spacetime?

Tags: cosmology, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I was recently wondering the following:

QFT in curved space time tell us that the Friedman Walker metric yields particles ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9707062.pdf)). At what order/scale will one be able to notice the back reaction of this particle creation on the Einstein's field equation which need to be satisfied (I was thinking of doing this perturbatively)?

I'm sure people must have already tried to calculate this kind of stuff but I couldn't find anything in the literature (after a quick google)